# Table column with text-overflow:ellipsis and a number besides

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a column `width: auto`. It contains a text, which is shortened by the ellipsis when it doesn't fit a column.

Now, I want to append a number besides the text. However, I still want the text to be shortened when it is too long, but the number has to be visible anyway. Below are a few illustrations of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image: Long name shortened when the column is large]
[image: Long name shortened when the column is small]
[image: Short name unchanged]

It is also required that the number stays near the text at all times. I can make it work when the number is at the fixed position by setting the text's `div.text { width: 95% }`, but this is not entirely satisfactory.

Please, take a look at JSFiddle to get the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRZfk/. The JSFiddle does not work as I would like it to because the width of the text is fixed.

Is it possible to solve this problem without using JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `max-width` instead `width` **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRZfk/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

I think replacing width:95% with max-width:95% does what you want? Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jvSuM/)

```
.text {
    max-width:95%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use trick with `::before` and `width` thgough almost the whole cell.

```
.text::before{
    content:'… (1)';
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    color: gray;
    left: 70%;
    background: pink;
}
```

- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRZfk/2/)

Comment: This would be fine if the number was the same everywhere but they are different for each element in the table.